(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section. Ubuntu on vmware
I am not sure what I am missing. This is a customized Ubuntu install I recieved and when I attempt to startX I am getting an error "Server terminated with error (1). Please assist as I have provided the logs from /var/log/Xorg.0.log.
    [  2543.027]
    
        X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
        X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
        [  2543.038] Current Ope

rating System: Linux jots7 5.15.0-84-generic #93-Ubuntu>
    [  2543.038] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic root=/d>
    [  2543.050] xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1 (For technical support ple>
    [  2543.053] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    [  2543.060]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
            to make sure that you have the latest version.
    [  2543.060] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
            (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
            (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    [  2543.073] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri May 24 15:23:27 20>
    [  2543.076] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
    [  2543.079] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    [  2543.083] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    [  2543.084] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
    [  2543.084] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
    [  2543.084] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
    [  2543.085] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
    [  2543.085] (==) Automatically adding devices
    [  2543.085] (==) Automatically enabling devices
    [  2543.085] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
    [  2543.085] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
    [  2543.085] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
    [  2543.085] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
    [  2543.085]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [  2543.085] (==) FontPath set to:
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
            /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
            built-ins
    [  2543.085] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    [  2543.085] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input device>
            If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevi>
    [  2543.085] (II) Loader magic: 0x555cd78eb020
    [  2543.085] (II) Module ABI versions:
    [  2543.085]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    [  2543.085]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
    [  2543.085]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
    [  2543.085]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
    [  2543.087] (++) using VT number 2
    [  2543.089] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/logi>
    [  2543.092] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
    [  2543.092] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.0/drm/c>
    [  2543.093] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 13 paused 0
    [  2543.109] (--) PCI:*(0@0:15:0) 15ad:0405:15ad:0405 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe8000000/1>
    [  2543.109] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
    [  2543.109] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
    [  2543.111] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.111]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.0
    [  2543.111]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
    [  2543.111] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
    [  2543.111] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
    [  2543.111] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.111]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
    [  2543.111]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  2543.111]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.111] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
    [  2543.111] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
    [  2543.112] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
    [  2543.112] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    [  2543.112] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
    [  2543.112] (==) Matched vmware as autoconfigured driver 0
    [  2543.112] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
    [  2543.112] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
    [  2543.112] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
    [  2543.112] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
    [  2543.112] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
    [  2543.112] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
    [  2543.146] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.146]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 13.3.0
    [  2543.146]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  2543.146]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.146] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
    [  2543.146] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
    [  2543.146] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.146]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.21.1
    [  2543.146]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  2543.146]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.146] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
    [  2543.147] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
    [  2543.147] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.147]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
    [  2543.147]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  2543.147]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.147] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
    [  2543.147] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
    [  2543.147] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.147]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
    [  2543.147]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  2543.147]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.147] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    [  2543.147] (II) Unloading vesa
    [  2543.147] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
    [  2543.147] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
    [  2543.147] (II) vmware: driver for VMware SVGA: vmware0405, vmware0710
    [  2543.147] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
    [  2543.147] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
    [  2543.147] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
    [  2543.148] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
    [  2543.148] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
    [  2543.148] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
    [  2543.148] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
    [  2543.148] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
    [  2543.148] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [  2543.148]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
    [  2543.148]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
    [  2543.148] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
    [  2543.148] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    [  2543.148] (--) vmware(0): DRM driver version is 2.19.0
    [  2543.148] (**) vmware(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
    [  2543.148] (==) vmware(0): RGB weight 888
    [  2543.148] (==) vmware(0): Default visual is TrueColor
    [  2543.148] (--) vmware(0): Min width 1, Max Width 8192.
    [  2543.148] (--) vmware(0): Min height 1, Max Height 8192.
    [  2543.148] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 using monitor section Configured Monitor
    [  2543.148] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual2 has no monitor section
    [  2543.148] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual3 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual4 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual5 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual6 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual7 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual8 has no monitor section
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Printing probed modes for output Virtual1
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "custom"x59.9  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 106>
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "966x582"x60.0   49.01  966 1016 1066 1116  582 632 682 732 -h>
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   85.50  1360 1424 1536 1792  768 771 777 795 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.8   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x768"x59.9   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 778 798 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 >
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsy>
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 489 492 525 -hsyn>
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual2
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual3
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual4
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual5
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual6
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual7
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual8
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 connected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual2 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual3 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual4 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual5 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual6 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual7 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual8 disconnected
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Using user preference for initial modes
    [  2543.149] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 using initial mode custom +0+0
    [  2543.149] (==) vmware(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
    [  2543.149] (==) vmware(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    [  2543.149] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
    [  2543.149] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
    [  2543.149] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
    [  2543.149] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
    [  2543.150] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
    [  2543.150] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
    [  2543.150] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
    [  2543.150] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
    [  2543.150] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
    [  2543.150] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
    [  2543.150] (II) Unloading modesetting
    [  2543.150] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
    [  2543.150] (II) Unloading fbdev
    [  2543.150] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
    [  2543.150] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
    [  2543.150] (II) vmware(0): Initialized VMWARE_CTRL extension version 0.2
    [  2543.152] (WW) vmware(0): Failed to initialize Gallium3D Xa. No render acceleration available.
    [  2543.152] (WW) vmware(0): Skipped initialization of direct rendering due to lack of render accele>
    [  2543.152] (--) vmware(0): Render acceleration is disabled.
    [  2543.152] (==) vmware(0): Rendercheck mode is disabled.
    [  2543.152] (--) vmware(0): Direct rendering (DRI2 3D) is disabled.
    [  2543.152] (--) vmware(0): Direct rendering (DRI3 3D) is disabled.
    [  2543.152] (==) vmware(0): Backing store enabled
    [  2543.152] (==) vmware(0): Silken mouse enabled
    [  2543.153] (==) vmware(0): DPMS enabled
    [  2543.153] (II) vmware(0): No 3D acceleration. Not setting up textured video.
    [  2543.153] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
    [  2543.153] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
    [  2543.153] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
    [  2543.154] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
    [  2543.155] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension Present
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
    [  2543.156] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
    [  2543.156] (II) Initializing extension GLX
    [  2543.157] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
    [  2543.166] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
    [  2543.166] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
    [  2543.166] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
    [  2543.166] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
    [  2543.166] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
    [  2543.166] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
    [  2543.167] (EE)
    Fatal server error:
    [  2543.167] (EE) failed to create screen resources(EE)
    [  2543.167] (EE)
    Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
             at http://wiki.x.org
     for help.
    [  2543.167] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
    [  2543.167] (EE)
    [  2543.175] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

If I understand your question this is not a version of Ubuntu supplied by the original maker. It is something someone has made for you?

I was able to resolve this from another forum post here:
How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?
Updating grub here "quiet splash nomodeset":
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


Is this a Ubuntu OS?
